# Multithreading does not change speed

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am currently working on speeding up one of my c++ program, and trying to discover the beautiful world of multithreading.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threadPool;
threadPool.clear();
for(int t = 0; t < nbThreads; ++t){
    threadPool.push_back(std::thread(myFunction, std::ref(rep), std::ref(branch1));
}
for(auto t = threadPool.begin(); t < threadPool.end() ; ++t){
    t->join();
}
```

What I don't understand is that whatever the number of threads I use, the speed does not change! (about 30sec).

**To sum up :** If my code is wrong, what is wrong? If it is not wrong, in what case should I use multithreading to speed up the computation?

**Edit :**  I run on a i7-4810MQ machine

**Edit 2 :** here is what myFunction does (it parses xml files)

```
void myfunction(DIR*& rep, struct dirent*& branch1){
mtx.lock();
while ((branch1 = readdir(rep)) != NULL){
    mtx.unlock()

    TiXmlDocument doc(branch1->d_name);
    if(doc.LoadFile()){
            //parse file
    }

    mtx.lock();
}
mtx.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Yes. No. No. No. Yes.

Comment: You are not showing how you are subdividing your work among your threads, and how they communicate their dependent results to each other (if any).

Comment: without the implementation of myFunction, it is hard to tell.

Comment: multithreading doesn't mean your code will run faster. more likely, it will run slower. unless you have multi core processor , the processor time will split between each thread, plus to overhead of creating them and switching between them.

Comment: If `myFunction(myArgument)` takes 30 seconds to execute and you pass it exactly the same to each thread, then it doesn't matter if one or a thousand threads do it, it will still take 30 seconds for each thread to complete it's work. You need to **split the work** between threads and design the implementation of `myFunction()` around that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance that your code is limited by file I/O. There's also a good chance that your XML parser makes lots of memory allocations, and memory allocations may slow down if many threads allocate memory simultaneously.

Comment: is there a way to check if it is really happening simultaneously or if the processes are sequenced ?